# How do you remove a CAEmitterLayer when it ends the lifetime of it's CAEmitter Cells -- instead of repeating until you remove it from super layer

Tags: ios, sdk, calayer, block

I am using generic code (from the iOS Fireworks demo) in a slightly changed way.  I have the following in a subclass of UIView.  What I want is to make the firework appear at the point the user touches (not hard) and play out for the length of the CAEmitterLayer/CAEmitterCells 'lifetime'.  Instead, this is immediately starting when i add it to addSublayer -- like I am sure it is meant to.  However, I would like to use it in a slightly different way.  Is there a way that I can change this so there is a CATransaction with a completion block (to removeFromSuperlayer) or something like that?  Any ideas are welcomed.

```
 #import "FireworksView.h"

    @implementation FireworksView

 - (void)launchFirework{

    //Load the spark image for the particle

    CAEmitterLayer *mortor = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
    mortor.emitterPosition = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height*(.75));
    mortor.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive;

    //Invisible particle representing the rocket before the explosion
    CAEmitterCell *rocket = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    rocket.emissionLongitude = -M_PI / 2;
    rocket.emissionLatitude = 0;
    rocket.lifetime = 1.6;
    rocket.birthRate = 1;
    rocket.velocity = 400;
    rocket.velocityRange = 100;
    rocket.yAcceleration = 250;
    rocket.emissionRange = M_PI / 4;
    rocket.color = CGColorCreateCopy([UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.5 blue:.5 alpha:.5].CGColor);
    rocket.redRange = 0.5;
    rocket.greenRange = 0.5;
    rocket.blueRange = 0.5;

    //Name the cell so that it can be animated later using keypath
    [rocket setName:@"rocket"];

    //Flare particles emitted from the rocket as it flys
    CAEmitterCell *flare = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    flare.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"tspark.png"].CGImage;
    flare.emissionLongitude = (4 * M_PI) / 2;
    flare.scale = 0.4;
    flare.velocity = 100;
    flare.birthRate = 45;
    flare.lifetime = 1.5;
    flare.yAcceleration = 350;
    flare.emissionRange = M_PI / 7;
    flare.alphaSpeed = -0.7;
    flare.scaleSpeed = -0.1;
    flare.scaleRange = 0.1;
    flare.beginTime = 0.01;
    flare.duration = 0.7;

    //The particles that make up the explosion
    CAEmitterCell *firework = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    firework.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"tspark.png"].CGImage;
    firework.birthRate = 9999;
    firework.scale = 0.6;
    firework.velocity = 130;
    firework.lifetime = 2;
    firework.alphaSpeed = -0.2;
    firework.yAcceleration = 80;
    firework.beginTime = 1.5;
    firework.duration = 0.1;
    firework.emissionRange = 2 * M_PI;
    firework.scaleSpeed = -0.1;
    firework.spin = 2;

    //Name the cell so that it can be animated later using keypath
    [firework setName:@"firework"];

    //preSpark is an invisible particle used to later emit the spark
    CAEmitterCell *preSpark = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    preSpark.birthRate = 80;
    preSpark.velocity = firework.velocity * 0.70;
    preSpark.lifetime = 1.7;
    preSpark.yAcceleration = firework.yAcceleration * 0.85;
    preSpark.beginTime = firework.beginTime - 0.2;
    preSpark.emissionRange = firework.emissionRange;
    preSpark.greenSpeed = 100;
    preSpark.blueSpeed = 100;
    preSpark.redSpeed = 100;

    //Name the cell so that it can be animated later using keypath
    [preSpark setName:@"preSpark"];

    //The 'sparkle' at the end of a firework
    CAEmitterCell *spark = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
    spark.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"tspark.png"].CGImage;
    spark.lifetime = 0.05;
    spark.yAcceleration = 250;
    spark.beginTime = 0.8;
    spark.scale = 0.4;
    spark.birthRate = 10;

    preSpark.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:spark, nil];
    rocket.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flare, firework, preSpark, nil];
    mortor.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rocket, nil];

    [self.layer addSublayer:mortor];
        }
```

Comment: I would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is, using CAEmitter, there is NO WAY -- delegate, etc -- to stop the emitter when it ends the cycle.  The only thing you can do is gracefully remove it from the layer when you think it should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I was able to sort of achieve this by creating an animation with delegate that fired along with the emitter. in the animationDidStop i made a for loop that went through my view hierarchy and looked for emitters and removed them. it's buggy and I still want a real solution, but this works for now.

```
for (CALayer *layer in _plusButton.layer.sublayers) {
    if (layer.class == [CAEmitterLayer class]) {
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }

}
```

Comment: You miss my point, I guess.  How do you TELL when the emitter has gotten to the end of the cycle?  :)

Comment: That's the thing, I cannot figure it out either, I was searching for the answer and found your question and thought I would post my workaround.